# Can anyone predict the scope of security in the year 2030?

Tags: user-education

I'm just curious to know the scope of the future security in terms of compliance and cyber security. And also the way of technology growth in terms of speed, authentication and authorization and OS.

And the most important thing is how the users are comfortable and use of ease with the security ?

Comment: Well, we hope it gets better? Given the advancing complexity of OS/program interaction, we know an enormous amount about what doesn't work, but everytime somebody announces they've got a handle on providing secure environments, yet another genius finds a new way to attack that sidesteps a lot of assumptions. IOW, no answer for something that's 15 years away. We already know the IOT is severely broken, with growth and watching the bottom line on expense by people who're creating the tech, the door's wide open.

Comment: Check the difference between 2000 and 2015, and add to the today.

Comment: This one is easy to answer: No.